# How does centering the data get rid of the intercept in regression and PCA?

Tags: regression, pca, centering

I keep reading about instances where we center the data (e.g., with regularization or PCA) in order to remove the intercept (as mentioned in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19523/need-for-centering-and-standardizing-data-in-regression)). I know it's simple, but I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding this. Could someone provide the intuition or a reference I can read?

Comment: This is a very special case of "controlling for other variables" as explained (in several ways) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/how-exactly-does-one-control-for-other-variables.  The "variable" being controlled for is the constant (intercept) term.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Can these pictures help?

The first 2 pictures are about regression. Centering the data does not alter the slope of regression line, but it makes intercept equal 0.

[image]

The pictures below are about PCA. PCA is a regressional model *without* intercept$^1$. Thus, principal components inevitably come through the origin. If you forget to center your data, the 1st principal component may pierce the cloud not along the main direction of the cloud, and will be (for statistics purposes) misleading.

[image]

---

$^1$ PCA isn't a regression *analysis*, of course. It however shares formally same linear equation (linear combination) with linear regression. PCA equation is like linear regression equation *without* intercept - because PCA is a rotation operation.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: in the case of regression, if I'm predicting y for an unseen x, that means I have to add the intercept back in *after* prediction, right? And, the intercept would be equal to $\bar{y} - \bar{X}\beta$?

Comment: Right. (Meaning "beta" in your formula is b for centered data, not standardized coefficient beta)

Comment: The second example is not correct. PCA is maximizing variance, so in the case of left uncentered data the direction found would be similar to right ("distance" of line from data cloud does not matter). The differences come in higher dimensions, where the data are complex and searching for the optimum direction should then be done from the center of the cloud.

Comment: `PCA is maximizing variance` This is not generally true. PCA maximizes (by the 1st PC) sum-of-squared deviations from the origin. Only if the data were preliminary centered (centering itself isn't a part of PCA) it turns to be maximizing variance.

Comment: P.S. Note that computation of covariances or correlations implies centering

Comment: > P.S. Note that computation of covariances or correlations implies centering – ttnphns Aug 27 '12 at 11:47 While I agree with your other comments, both covariance and correlation do NOT imply centering. Neither cor nor covar change value when an additive constant is applied to the data.

Comment: @ttnphns: Your second figure (about PCA) has one unfortunate drawback: 1st PC on the centered data is exactly orthogonal to the 1st PC on the un-centered data. As a result, it might make an impression that failing to center will only influence the 1st PC, and all the other principal axes will simply get shifted by one (1st become 2nd, etc.). This is of course not so. If your cloud on the left were rotated e.g. clockwise by 60 degrees (and if you also marked 2nd PCs on both subplots), this would become more obvious.

Comment: @amoeba, I could have been selecting better data for the example, but who cares? The truth is there. The "impression" you are talking about indeed might mislead somebody sagacious, like you, but a sagacious, like you, will then certainly get rid of the impression.

Comment: The pictures appear to be broken.

Comment: @GWW, what's wrong? You can't see the pictures?

Comment: @ttnphns: Yeah for some reason they are all shown as invalid image links. Perhaps it is an issue with SE?

Comment: @GWW, on my computer and my phone the pics display all right. So I can't say anything to your problem. Maybe you want to call a moderator's attention? You can do it by pressing "flag" below the answer and then expressing your finding.

Comment: @ttnphns: This is bizarre I don't understand why I cannot see them.  I have tried on two different computers but they do work on my phone.  Oh well, sorry to cause issue.

Comment: So...the reason to center the data, is just...to have the the values in center? The values are going to look the same, just a little bit futher away from center?

Comment: I mean, the slope, position, the style, look etc how the values are...are going to be the same, with and without centering the data?

Answer (score 1):

At least two references that I can find, an earlier edition of which I have been familiar with for about thirty years, state that there are four basic variants of PCA, using:

- Covariance about the mean - this is the variant of PCA which is most commonly referred to as 'PCA' by e.g. sklearn
- Covariance about the origin - this is the variant which results from using sklearn TruncatedSVD
- Correlation about the mean
- Correlation about the origin

PCA 'about the origin' is performed without mean-centring the data, and for 'correlation about', the correlation matrix is used instead of the covariance matrix.

Which variation you use will obviously affect downstream calculations, particularly forms of factor analysis.

From [Applications of Factor Analysis to Spectroscopic Methods](https://gala.gre.ac.uk/id/eprint/6117/1/Timothy%20Graham%20Brockwell%201992.pdf) (Brockwell, 1992):

> Correlation about the mean is the traditional form of pre-processing
> applied before factor analysis, it maintains the Spatial information
> contained in the data but looses both the origin and the magnitude of
> the original information. Correlation about the origin maintains the
> zero point of the data but still looses the relative size information.
> Covariance about the mean maintains the relative size information but
> looses the zero point of the data. Covariance about the origin does
> not alter the data in any way thus preserving the magnitude and origin
> information. The different techniques find uses depending upon the
> characteristics of the data; mass spectroscopy data has both an
> absolute zero point and a common scale for magnitude.
>
> The use of the four pre-treatments above was studied by [Rozett and
> Petersen](http://xrm.phys.northwestern.edu/research/pdf_papers/1975/rozett_analchem_1975.pdf) using the mass spectra of 22 alkyl benzenes and they
> concluded that with both R and Q analysis (R analysis has the data
> with rows composed of the samples and columns of spectra, Q analysis
> is the opposite) the use of covariance about the origin was the best
> method of pre-treatment as it preserved both the origin of the factor
> space at zero and also the relative sizes of the components.

References:

[Factor Analysis in Chemistry](https://ebin.pub/factor-analysis-in-chemistry-thirdnbsped-0471134791.html), Third Edition, Malinowski - 2002.

[BSR 2949](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/85236346.pdf) - Signature Data Processing Final Report - Volume II: Equations and Flow Diagrams, Crawford and Hanson, NASA, 1970.