# Centering variables before running PCA

Tags: pca, centering

I am learning about PCA, regarding PCA I need to know that given a dataset is it always necessary to use centering? what if I don't center the variables used in PCA?

Comment: see the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues/2698#2698)

Comment: Also of possible interest http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22331/3277