# Will I miss anomalies/outliers due to PCA?

Tags: pca, outliers, dimensionality-reduction

My final goal is to detect anomalies (outliers) in a high dimensional space. I was planning to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality as to be able to notice such anomalies better. But then I thought about it and made a counter example how PCA could even make things worse, even though the space has less dimensions.

Here's an example. From the first picture we can obviously see that the red point is an anomaly. When we perform PCA and get to 1 dimension this phenomena gets lost. I'm expecting that this could happen in the case of reducing not from 2D to 1D, but from N to M (M < N).

[image: Before PCA]

[image: After PCA]

I'm only looking for confirmation and additional thoughts on this, how big of a problem can this be? I'm guessing that we can loose quite of important information for the price of less dimensionality, as correlation between features can be lost.

---

EDIT: Here is also the case when we project onto two components. In this case the phenomena is kept (as expected), but I must emphasize that my initial goal was to reduce the dimensionality, which is not achieved in this case.

[image: Projection onto two components]

Comment: +1 good question. your example is only selecting 1 principle component, which lose information, may be we should also consider select all components.

Comment: @hxd1011 I have added the case when all components are kept, but that is not my goal, as I explain.

Comment: did you find any paper which explore this issue? @Marko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: It depends. If the sample in question is an outlier in a direction covered by your extracted PCs (i.e. where most variance occurs) you'll keep the information, if its an outlier in a direction orthogonal to all extracted PCs you'll loose it.

To be honest: Reduction to only one single PC is an extreme case. When applying PCA in high dimensionl space one would rarely use only one PC.

If in contrast you have lots of resulting final PCs, wouldn't it be a sensible assumption, that PCs that explain only a very small amount of total variance und thus get dropped finally, are also not relevant for outlier detection?

All that said: Generally the motivation to apply PCA would be driven by the assumption that all dimensions in your space are of approximately equal importance (with the final weight defined by the selected scaling of the features), and there is no idea to preselect a small subset of relevant dimensions based on some domain knowledge. Is that the case here? Otherwise selection of features based on domain knowledge would be far better.

Comment: Thank you. Well, I would say that this is something which depends from angle of view "PCs that explain only a very small amount of total variance are also not relevant for outlier detection", well wouldn't it be a "bigger" anomaly if there is variation in something which varies rarely, then in something that varies all the time? What do you think by "with the final weight defined by the selected scaling of the features", do you literally mean that weights of PCs depend on scale of features?

Comment: To your points: a) yes, I agree; so I'd not throw the respective low variance feature into a PCA, as PCA is oriented towards sources of biggest variance, and thes low variance variables will kind of vanish there (some attribute selection methods even drop low variance features explicitly); rather I'd select it separately and intentionally if seemingly reasonable (thus the hint to domain knowledge); b) That means the weight of the feature considered, when it get's processed in PCA, as you can either standardize attributes for PCA or leave them in the original (or another intended) scaling.

Comment: So, to conclude - it could happen that PCA leads to loosing notion of anomalies in certain cases (the ones which you described in your answer) and it would be (possibly) smarter to include features with smaller variance by default and to perform PCA on the once with "similar" variability. Do you agree? Final thoughts, what is your opinion whether attributes should be standardized prior to PCA?

Comment: There are quite some threads here discussing the issue of scaling/standardizing etc. Maybe you'd like to have a look at the following blog entries:

http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/05/pcr_part1_xonly/

http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/05/pcr_part2_yaware/