# Unit tests for lasso?

Tags: regression, lasso

I have my own implementation for non-negative lasso, but not sure if it is right. Any idea where can I find unit tests to verify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the best place to ask this kind of questions...
However, you can use the `glmnet` package, in R and run a LASSO with the package. Then, saving the data (csv per example), you can run your own algorithm and compare the estimated coefficients. Be careful though, `glmnet` handles pretty much all the scaling for you (even the answer can be rescaled, more information here : [Lasso centering and standarization with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173410/lasso-centering-and-standarization-with-r/173454#173454))